# how to use if condition in xml

Tags: php, xml

I want convert this code to php code.
I have tried a lot using str_replace function. But the codes are printed not be executed

```
<if condition=""></if>
```

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates>
    <template name="users">
    <![CDATA[
    <div class="navber">
        <if condition="$show['member']">
            <div class="usercp">{usercp}</div>
            <div class="logout">{logout}</div>
        </if>
        <if condition="$show['visiter']">
            <div class="register">{register}</div>
            <div class="login">{login}</div>
        </if>
    </div>
    ]]>
    </template>
</templates>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
function load($temp){
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('style.xml');
        $xml = $xml->template[$temp];
        $xml = str_replace('<if condition="">','<?php if(){ ?>',$xml);
        $xml = str_replace('</if>','<?php } ?>',$xml);
        echo $xml;
    }
?>
```

How can I make the browser executes the PHP codes.
Thank you

Comment: This is a very strange process as XML is not a script file (unless using XSLT) to relay programming instructions and nor is it a text file to be converted to PHP code. Reconsider your end-to-end needs.